# swift isUserInteractionEnabled = false not working inside UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, isuserinteractionenabled

I have a problem where I have a UIScrollView and a Header (UIView) inside my main View and my Header is over my UIScrollView as such:

```
UIView.
|
|- UIScrollView.
|
|- Header. (UIView)
```

I want my header to be able to detect taps on it, but I also want my scroll view to be able to scroll when I drag over my Header which right now it is not possible because my Header is over it and is blocking the scroll.

**To sum up, I want my Header to detect taps but forward scrolls to my UIScrollView.**

To tackle this problem I tried multiple things, and here are some of them:

1. Adding a UIPanGestureRecognizer to my Header so it is able to detect dragging
2. Adding a UITapGestureRecognizer to my Header so it is able to detect tapping
3. Setting isUserInteractionEnabled = false when dragging begins so the gesture can be passed to the next UIResponder which in this case is my UIScrollView
4. Setting isUserInteractionEnabled = true once my dragging has finished so it can again detect tapping

This is the code snippet:

```
    override func viewLoad() {
        myScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(handlePan))
        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(handleTap(_:)))
        headerView.addGestureRecognizer(myScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer)
        headerView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
    }

    @objc func handlePan(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer){
        print("dragging")
        if headerView.isUserInteractionEnabled{
            headerView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        }
        if sender.state == .began {
        } else if sender.state == .ended {
            headerView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        }
    }

    @objc func handleTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer){
        print("tapped")
    }
```

At this point I see how dragging and tapping are being detected just fine, but for some reason isUserInteractionEnabled = false seems to not be changing how the view is behaving. This code is acting as isUserInteractionEnabled is always true no mater what.

Things that I have also tried besides this:

- overriding the hitTest function inside UIButton
- overriding touchesBegan, touchesMoved, touchesEnded methods overriding next
- setting the variable to return ScrollView as the next UIResponder
- setting the isExclusiveTouch method in UIButton
- changing the isUserInteractionEnabled in every way possible

Comment: Yes it will, if you set isUserInteractionEnabled = false to the header view from the beginning and you drag on it it will automatically be sent to the UIScrollView no mater what

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with this problem too, you should try to use methods of `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` which allows you to handle simultaneous gestures.

1. Connect your gesture recognizers delegates e.g. `tapGestureRecognizer.delegate = self`
2. Make your ViewController conform this protocol e.g.
   `extension YourViewController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {}`
3. Implement this function:

   ```
   func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool { return true }
   ```

Comment: So I did this, but I am still not able to scroll my UIScrollView when I drag inside my Header :(

Comment: Ou I’ve missed that you don’t have headerView inside the scroll view, because you want’t sticky header? Well than you need to manually scroll the scrollView. The PanGestureRecognizer is now working right? I would delete the lines inside `handlePan`which are setting `isUserInteractionEnabled`. And I would use sender.translation for setting scrollView.contentOffset.

Comment: That is a possible way to scroll UIScrollView behind but the problem is the scroll wont feel as if you were scrolling from the UIScrollView itself, it wont have that same smoothness and that is the reason why I try using isUserInteractionEnabled, because when isUserInteractionEnabled = false the scroll over your scrollView is as if you where scrolling from the UIScrollView itself.